# Access loss and model in a custom callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I read this https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback, but I don't know how I could get all the other parameters.

This is my code

```
 (hits, ndcgs) = evaluate_model(model, testRatings, testNegatives, topK, evaluation_threads)
  hr, ndcg, loss = np.array(hits).mean(), np.array(ndcgs).mean(), hist.history['loss'][0]
  print('Iteration %d [%.1f s]: HR = %.4f, NDCG = %.4f, loss = %.4f [%.1f s]' 
                  % (epoch,  t2-t1, hr, ndcg, loss, time()-t2))
 if hr > best_hr:
     best_hr, best_ndcg, best_iter = hr, ndcg, epoch
 if args.out > 0:
     model.save(model_out_file, overwrite=True)
```

As you can see I need `model`, `hist` and `model.save`.
Is there a way to use these three parameters in a custom callback?
So that I can write all of this into a custom callback.

```
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):

   def on_epoch_end(self, logs=None):
       keys = list(logs.keys())
       print("Stop training; got log keys: {}".format(keys))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The model is an [attribute of `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback#attributes), so you can access it directly with `self.model`. For accessing the value of the loss, you can use the "logs" object that is passed to the [methods of `tf.keras.callbacks.Callback`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback#methods), that will contain a key named "loss".

If you need to access to other variables (that won't change during the training), then you can set them as instance variables of your callback, and add them during the construction of the callback by defining the `__init__` function.

```
class CustomCallback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
   def __init__(self, testRatings, testNegatives, topK, evaluation_threads):
       super().__init__()
       self.testRatings = testRatings
       self.testNegatives = testNegatives
       self.topK = topK
       self.evaluation_threads = evaluation_threads

   def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
       logs = logs or {}
       current_loss = logs.get("loss")
       if current_loss:
           print("my_loss: ", current_loss)
       print("my_model", self.model)
       # the attributes are accessble with self
       print("my topK atributes", self.topK)

# you can then create the callback by passing the correct attributes
my_callback = CustomCallback(testRatings, testNegatives, topK, evaluation_threads)
```

---

**Note**: If what you want to do is evaluate the model between each epoch, and save the model if the model got the best metrics, I suggest you give a look to:

- The [`fit` function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?hl=en#fit), where you can actually provide a testing set
- The [metrics module](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics?hl=en), that provides metrics that will be computed on the train and the test set
- The [`ModelCheckpoint` callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint), that will save the model at each epoch, keeping the best weights if providing the option `save_best_only`

Comment: thank you very much! So `self` is the `model` ? Could I also save the `model` and get the `model` ? And I apologize  the code should do that at every end of an epoch.

Comment: You can define the `on_epoch_end` method to do it at each epoch. `self` is a keyword that references the object, see the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks), so in that case, it reference the callback object. If you want to save the model, you can access the model through the attribute, so `self.model.save("/path/to/saved_model")` would do the trick.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! Is there also the option to pass a parameter to the callback?
For example, I'm using `testRatings, testNegatives, topK, evaluation_threads` here. Can this be passed on to the callback?

Comment: Yes, you can pass that in the `__init__` function (the constructor) of your callback. They will be accessible as "instance variables", you can read more about it in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)

Comment: Thank you, I read about it. Unfortunately, I don't get it right. Could you please show me a code example?

Comment: Thank you. If I call this `CALLBACKS = [CustomCallback(test[['receipt_id_ano', 'gtin_ano']].values, test_negative, constant.TOPK, 1)]` `model.fit(callbacks = CALLBACKS)` I got `TypeError: on_epoch_end() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: I made a mistake in my example when defining `on_epoch_end`. I fixed it.